# User click on the Search Button Multiple times the crystal report becomes hang

Tags: c#, winforms, crystal-reports

I created an crystal Report application in which I am generating the monthly report with Search Button. when User click on the Search Button Multiple times the crystal report becomes hang and show the **"Not Responding"** message on title bar. so how can I avoid such situation so that my reposrt doesn't get hang, and it works properly.

Also I attach the screen shot of crystal viewer when user click multiple time on Search Button and viewer becomes hang.

[image]

```
Report objReport = null;

private void cmdSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OleDbDataAdapter objoleDbAdapter = null;
    objReport = new Report();

    DataSet sonoDataset = new DataSet();

     //Db Logic here

    objReport.Close();
    objReport.SetDataSource(sonoDataset);
    crtViewer.ReportSource = objReport;
    objReport.Refresh();

    objOleDbCommand.Dispose();
    objOleDbCommand = null;
    objoleDbAdapter.Dispose();
    objoleDbAdapter = null;
}
```

This is my just simple code on search button. but i dont understand why Crystal Report is hang while click on search button.

Comment: What about some code? 
Best practice will be to disable the "Search" button until work has done, then re-enable it.

Comment: @etaiso thanks for your reply,I tryed this solution. but any other different answer for it.

Comment: I agree with etaise to provide some code, especially for your search button. You could do a check to see if the CR process is running when someone clicks the Search button, and if it's running, then don't start it again.

Comment: @etaiso I added the code that i write

Comment: @campagnolo_1  I add code that I write, in which nothing is complicated just to search and display

Comment: Not knowing your application, open your taskmanager, switch to Processes. Then click your search button and see if a new process starts. If there is a new process starting, write down the name of that process and get back to us.